# Combine Drawer.Navigator and Stack.Navigator without creating separate navigation bars

Tags: react-native

I would like to have stack and drawer navigators use the same navigation bar. However, both are creating their own navigation bars refer to the below image making the app look messy. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Below is my code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Contact from "../screens/Contact";
import About from "../screens/About";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const HomeNavigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'         
    screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign:'center',
        //headerShown: false
        }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Contact' component={Contact} />
      <Stack.Screen name='About' component={About} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MenuNavigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'     
    screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign:'center',
        //headerShown: false
        }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Menu' component={About} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const DrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name='HomeNavigation' component={HomeNavigation} /> 
      <Drawer.Screen name='MenuNavigation' component={MenuNavigation} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

Comment: So from your code, it looks like you want the drawer navigator to navigate to two different stack navigators. (One important note is that you should `Stack1 = createStackNavigator()` and `Stack2 = createStackNavigator()` as if they were in seperate files) and the drawer navigator by default shows the first screen available to it which is `HomeNavigation` which has it's default Screen set as Home screen. So you can just hide the top bar in <Home /> with `options = {{headerShown : false}}`

Comment: i want to be able to go back after visiting different pages so **options = {{headerShown : false}}** is not a good idea is there no any other way?

Comment: Yeah, users might still be able to go back through hardware options (like the Back Button on Android, and the left to right screen swipe on iOS, don't know about Web. Windows, etc), but if you want a button, you might just add a manual one with `onClick = {navigation.goBack}`? Not exactly sure if there's a simpler way through documentation